# Persist web socket connection objects on data store

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, chat

I am using a web socket library on server for establishing socket connection.

`https://github.com/websockets/ws`

As i am going to have a node server to host this socket server, i might need to have multiple servers inside a cluster. So, for that i want to persist the socket objects into a data store. Thus, in that way those objects are shareable across the server processes.

Comment: You're probably going to want to use Redis for that.

Comment: I hope you don't think that by sharing those objects you can use the same Websocket connection on all servers? Because underneath there's a TCP connection and a local socket managed by the OS...

Comment: @Mörre I don't want to share the objects. We can keep some client info also on server to recreate the socket connection on server.

Comment: @Shadowfool I can use Redis to trigger events across the server to broadcast the messages. In that case each server will have their in memory clients list. But, the problem is what if server crashes or a need to restart the server occurs in that case all in memory clients will get lost.

Comment: The point is you store the clients on redis not in memory. That way if one of your server instances goes down, redis still knows which clients are connected. Redis would be either deployed as many instances where data is replicated across or as a single instance that your many servers talk to.

Comment: @Shadowfool could you please provide an example of what exact connection data would need to be saved to Redis for this to work? Thanks!